# Failed Gauss-Jordan elimination implementation in C#

Tags: c#, matrix

Based on the alorithm given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Pseudocode,
I tried to implement a C# version of the Gaussian Elimination:

```
public Matrix GaussianElimination(double epsilon = 1e-10)
{
    var result = Copy();

    var kMax = Math.Min(result.RowCount, result.ColumnCount);

    for (var k = 0; k < kMax; k++)
    {
        // Find k-th pivot, i.e. maximum in column max
        var iMax = result.FindColumnAbsMax(k);

        if (Math.Abs(result[iMax, k]) < epsilon)
        {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Matrix is singular or nearly singular.");
        }

        // Swap maximum row with current row
        SwapRows(k, iMax);

        // Make all rows below the current one, with 0 in current column
        for (var i = k + 1; i < result.RowCount; i++)
        {
            var factor = result[i, k] / result[k, k];

            for (var j = k + 1; j < result.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                result[i, j] = result[i, j] - result[k, j] * factor;
            }

            result[i, k] = 0;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

It works in most cases (note that this is not performing the back substitution step). However, for the first example given in Wikipedia, the algorithm stop on the singular matrix case and throw the related exception on the row echelon form right before back substitution step with:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var matrix = Matrix.Parse("[1 3 1 9; 1 1 -1 1; 3 11 5 35]");

        Console.WriteLine(matrix);

        Console.WriteLine(matrix.GaussianElimination());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

- k = 2
- kMax = 3
- iMax = 2
- result = [1 3 1 9; 0 -2 -2 -8; 0 0 0 0]

[EDIT]
The Matrix implementation is a bit lengthy but here is what it is used in regard to the string parsing and the elimination method:

```
public class Matrix
{
    public const string MatrixStart = "[";
    public const string MatrixStop = "]";
    public const char RowSeparator = ';';
    public const char RowCellSeparator = ' ';

    public int RowCount { get; }

    public int ColumnCount { get; }

    public int CellCount => _data.Length;

    public bool IsSquare => RowCount == ColumnCount;

    public bool IsVector => ColumnCount == 1;

    private readonly double[] _data;

    public double this[int rowIndex, int columnIndex]
    {
        get => _data[Convert2DIndexTo1DIndex(rowIndex, columnIndex)];
        set => _data[Convert2DIndexTo1DIndex(rowIndex, columnIndex)] = value;
    }

    public Matrix(Matrix matrix)
        : this(matrix.RowCount, matrix.ColumnCount)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < _data.Length; i++)
        {
            _data[i] = matrix._data[i];
        }
    }

    public Matrix(int size, double placeHolder = 0)
        : this(size, size, placeHolder)
    {
    }

    public Matrix(int rowCount, int columnCount, double initializationValue = 0)
    {
        if (rowCount < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(rowCount));
        }
        if (columnCount < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(columnCount));
        }

        RowCount = rowCount;
        ColumnCount = columnCount;
        _data = new double[RowCount * ColumnCount];

        if (Math.Abs(initializationValue) > 0)
        {
            Set(initializationValue);
        }
    }

    public Matrix(int rowCount, int columnCount, double[] initializationValues)
    {
        if (rowCount < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(rowCount));
        }
        if (columnCount < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(columnCount));
        }
        if (initializationValues.Length != rowCount * columnCount)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(initializationValues));
        }

        RowCount = rowCount;
        ColumnCount = columnCount;
        _data = new double[initializationValues.Length];
        initializationValues.CopyTo(_data, 0);
    }

    private int Convert2DIndexTo1DIndex(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        return rowIndex * ColumnCount + columnIndex;
    }

    public void Set(double value)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < _data.Length; i++)
        {
            _data[i] = value;
        }
    }

    public Matrix Transpose()
    {
        var result = new Matrix(ColumnCount, RowCount);

        for (var i = 0; i < result.RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < result.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                result[i, j] = this[j, i];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public Matrix Copy()
    {
        return new Matrix(this);
    }

    private int FindColumnAbsMax(int index)
    {
        return FindColumnAbsMax(index, index);
    }

    private int FindColumnAbsMax(int rowStartIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        var maxIndex = rowStartIndex;

        for (var i = rowStartIndex + 1; i < RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(this[maxIndex, columnIndex]) <= Math.Abs(this[i, columnIndex]))
            {
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }

        return maxIndex;
    }


    public void SwapRows(int rowIndexA, int rowIndexB)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            var indexA = Convert2DIndexTo1DIndex(rowIndexA, j);
            var indexB = Convert2DIndexTo1DIndex(rowIndexB, j);

            _data.Swap(indexA, indexB);
        }
    }

    public void SwapColumns(int columnIndexA, int columnIndexB)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
        {
            var indexA = Convert2DIndexTo1DIndex(i, columnIndexA);
            var indexB = Convert2DIndexTo1DIndex(i, columnIndexB);

            _data.Swap(indexA, indexB);
        }
    }

    public static Matrix Parse(string matrixString)
    {
        if (!matrixString.StartsWith(MatrixStart) || !matrixString.EndsWith(MatrixStop))
        {
            throw new FormatException();
        }

        matrixString = matrixString.Remove(0, 1);
        matrixString = matrixString.Remove(matrixString.Length - 1, 1);

        var rows = matrixString.Split(new[] { RowSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (rows.Length <= 0)
        {
            return new Matrix(0, 0);
        }

        var cells = ParseRow(rows[0]);
        var matrix = new Matrix(rows.Length, cells.Length);

        for (var j = 0; j < cells.Length; j++)
        {
            matrix[0, j] = cells[j];
        }

        for (var i = 1; i < matrix.RowCount; i++)
        {
            cells = ParseRow(rows[i]);

            for (var j = 0; j < cells.Length; j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = cells[j];
            }
        }

        return matrix;
    }

    private static double[] ParseRow(string row)
    {
        var cells = row.Split(new [] { RowCellSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return cells.Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.Replace(" ", string.Empty))).ToArray();
    }
}
```

And the 1D Array extension for swapping two items:

```
public static class ArrayHelpers
{
    public static void Swap<TSource>(this TSource[] source, int indexA, int indexB)
    {
        var tmp = source[indexA];
        source[indexA] = source[indexB];
        source[indexB] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. (1) What is the `Matrix` type? and; (2) what is the implementation of `SwapRows()` method?

Comment: @Svek I just edited my question, (1) Matrix type is a custom class, (2) SwapRows implementation is given above.